# Positioning a body in space using intersection criteria...

Tags: geometry

(Sorry there is an error in my images below - the coordinates of point A1 should be 0,0,-86.6. I'm not sure how to replace the images. Sorry for the confusion).

I hope this post is appropriate for this forum.  If not I apologize.  I’m scratching my head over a math problem that I’d like to solve and could use a bit of assistance.  Unfortunately I’m an engineer and while the math is of great interest I don’t even know the realm to start in. I’m sort of assuming this is some sort of matrix problem but I’m not sure.

The problem involves positioning objects in space to determine a resultant location that satisfies some intersection criteria. Because it’s a bit hard to describe I have a couple of pages describing the basic problem that follow.

I used a CAD system to graphically solve for one case. I’d ideally like to reduce this to a generalized case that I can use to solve for a given set of inputs.

I believe that there are two possible solutions (one with the prism above and one with the prism below) however there may be situations with multiple additional solutions that might render this more complicated. If it helps, I can constrain the solution so that the focal point is always a negative X and positive Y value.  I believe this reduces this down to a single solution (but I’m not positive)

I would love not just a solution (which would be cool) but also to learn how this sort of problem is solved). I believe this is a fairly common imaging problem and my CAD system can solve it graphically (or perhaps mathematically behind the scenes) so there must be a solution out there someplace. Thanks in advance for any guidance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The coordinates of $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ cannot be those given in your first page, if $A_1A_2A_3$ is an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Argh!  I am embarassed. Yes, of course,  A1 is 0,0,86.6.  Sorry.  I will try to edit

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward method is that of finding $a=A_1F$, $b=A_2F$, $c=A_3F$ (where point $F$ is the "focus", i.e. the vertex of the pyramid), solving the following system of three equations:
$$
a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b 
\left(1 - {47^2\over2\cdot300^2}\right)=100^2\\
b^2 + c^2 - 2 b c 
\left(1 - {66^2\over2\cdot300^2}\right)=100^2\\
c^2 + a^2 - 2 c a 
\left(1 - {68^2\over2\cdot300^2}\right)=100^2
$$ 
These are obtained by the cosine law applied to triangles $FA_1A_2$, $FA_2A_3$, $FA_3A_1$, and the cosines of the angles, in turn, are found from triangles $FB_1B_2$, $FB_2B_3$, $FB_3B_1$.

This is a system leading to quartic equations for $a^2$, $b^2$, $c^2$ and an exact solution is thus possible but quite impractical. Hence a numerical method should be used to find the solutions. With the above numbers, for instance, we get two different real positive solutions:
$$
{a = 370.5199, b = 447.527, c = 416.112}
\quad\text{and}\quad
{a = 439.484, b = 361.3693, c = 413.911}.
$$

EDIT.

To get the coordinates of $F=(x,y,z)$ from the above result, you must solve another system of three equations:
$$
(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z-z_1)^2=a^2\\
(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2+(z-z_2)^2=b^2\\
(x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2+(z-z_3)^2=c^2\\
$$
where $A_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)=(0,0,-50\sqrt3)$, $A_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)=(-50,0,0)$, 
$A_3=(x_3,y_3,z_3)=(50,0,0)$. Fortunately, this is a quadratic system of equations, because subtracting two pairs of equations one from the other we get two linear equations. Hence there are only two solutions, differing for the sign of $y$:
$$
x = {b^2 - c^2\over200},\quad z=\frac{2 a^2-b^2-c^2-10000}{200 \sqrt{3}}\\
{\quad\ }\\
{\quad\ }\\
y=\pm\frac{\sqrt{-a^4+a^2 b^2+a^2 c^2+10000 a^2-b^4+b^2 c^2+10000 b^2-c^4+10000
   c^2-100000000}}{100 \sqrt{3}}.
$$
Plugging here the above values for $a$, $b$, $c$ we obtain the solutions:
$$
F=(135.654, \pm258.957, -314.252)
\quad\text{and}\quad
F=(-203.671, \pm246.71, 214.725).
$$

Comment: Aretino,  thank you so very much.  I am sorry about the error in the coordinates of the equilateral triangle. That was a silly mistake.  I am sorry but I don't clearly understand your approach. I think I understand that you can determine the angles present in the prism / (pyramid) comprised of triangle B and the focal point - and these same angles are obviously present all the way down to the points on triangle A (which lie on another plane).  But I had expected an answer for the focal point in cartesian coordinates.  in your explanation, can you please define a, b and c?

Comment: Also, you comment "Hence a numerical method should be used".  I'm not sure I understand? Sorry for my ignorance but what are "numerical methods"  is this using a computer to guess, compute and adjust?  If no math solution is practical I am wondering how computer vision and image processing algorithms work. Thank you so very much. I loved math in school and really enjoy this sort of exercise.  I just don't know it very well.

Comment: @DaveFranchino Quantities $a$, $b$, $c$ are defined at the very beginning of my answer: they are the distances from the "focus" to the vertices of triangle $A_1A_2A_3$. Once you have found them, it is not difficult to find the coordinates of the focus: I'll expand on that later. Finally, I'm not an expert in numerical solution of equations, but there are standard algorithms to find the roots of a polynomial, and yes: image processing algorithms probably include them.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so very much. I'm new to this forum but if it's possible to give you some credit I will determine how to do that. I'm writing a simple Processing program to help solve this. Thank you o this has been fun.

Comment: can I ask how you solved the system of equations above using a numerical method?  did you do it online using something like Wolfram Alpha or is there another method to obtain these? Ultimately I will need to be able to incorporate a method of solving this into a computer program. I am new to numeric methods but learning. if there is a good reference on a computer approach to solving a system of quadratic equations I would be grateful. Thank you.  PS I am amazed at how quickly and efficiently you solved this. Wow!

Comment: @DaveFranchino I used Mathematica by Wolfram to solve the equations. I'm not an expert in numerical methods: you can google around, or even ask here (or possibly at Stack Overflow) a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

*Starting from @Aretino's answer;*

To get rid of big numbers, define $A=\frac a {100}$, $B=\frac b {100}$, $C=\frac c {100}$, write the equations as
$$A^2+B^2-k_1 A B=1 \tag 1$$
$$B^2+C^2-k_2 B C=1 \tag 2$$
$$C^2+A^2-k_3 C A=1 \tag 3$$

$$(1) \implies B_\pm=\frac{1}{2} \left(A k_1\pm\sqrt{A^2 k_1^2-4 A^2+4}\right)$$
$$(3) \implies C_\pm=\frac{1}{2} \left(A k_3\pm\sqrt{A^2 k_3^2-4 A^2+4}\right)$$ So, $(2)$ is left with four combinations but it is just a function of $A$ which is not a big deal (except that it corresponds to an octic polynomial in $A$).

However, Newton method would converge quite fast. For example, for the combination $(B_+,C_+)$, by inspection the root is around $3$ and the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & A_n \\
 0 & 3.00000 \\
 1 & 3.80093 \\
 2 & 3.70798 \\
 3 & 3.70520
\end{array}
\right)$$

This leads to

Comment: Claude,  Thanks but I'm still struggling. It's been very long (if ever) since I studied this so my questions are probably stupid. I recall using a Jacobian inverse / Newtons' method to solve a system of nonlinear equations but I believe that was only two equations.  I'm sort of lost. Ultimately I will need to reduce this to a computer program so that I can quickly solve this for varying values. Are you able to better explain your steps or direct me to a reference that can help with solving a system of three equations via computer?  Thanks and sorry to be needy!